# Error in the VXML?

Tags: php, vxml, voicexml, vonage

I am using the `voicexml` to handle the inbound calls from the customers. Here is the `vxml` I am using :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml version = "2.1" >

        <menu dtmf="true">
            <property name="inputmodes" value="dtmf"/>
            <prompt>Hello, Welcome! If you are an existing customer, press 1, For support press 2</prompt>
            <choice dtmf="1" next="#existing"/>
            <choice dtmf="2" next="#support"/>
        </menu>
        <form id="existing">
            <record name="recording" beep="true" maxtime="100s">
                <block>
                    <prompt>Please wait while we transfer the call</prompt>
                </block>
                 <transfer name="MyCall" dest="tel:+911111111111" bridge="true" connecttimeout="20s"/>
                <filled>
                    <submit next="call_inbound.php" method="post" namelist="recording" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
                </filled>
            </record>
        </form>

        <form id="support">
            <record name="recording" beep="true" maxtime="100s">
                    <block>
                        <prompt>Please wait while we transfer the call</prompt>
                    </block>
                    <transfer name="MyCall" dest="tel:+9111111111111" bridge="true" connecttimeout="20s"/>
                    <filled>
                        <submit next="call_inbound.php" method="post" namelist="recording" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
                    </filled>
            </record>
        </form>

</vxml>
```

Any idea, what is the error in the xml. There seems to be some error in the xml. If I remove the record tag, it works.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put form items (like block and transfer) inside another form item (i.e.  in your case). Use a validating XML editor and use the VoiceXML XSD schema to valudate.